# How to List items in array javascript

Tags: javascript, html

been working on this code. I want it to produce my array so it looks like this:

```
[0] cat

[1] dog

[2] *Whatever value entered by user*
```

Currently, it produces this

```
Pushed: *User Entered Value*

cat,dog,*user entered value*
```

Here's my code.

```
var array = ["cat", "dog"];
window.onload = function menu(){

var selection = prompt("Please use this menu, and type 1 to push an item on the array, 2 to pop an item off the array, and 3 to exit the menu.");

  if (selection == '1'){
    var push = prompt("What item would you like to push onto the array?");
      while (push != null) {    
        array.push(push);
        document.getElementById("pushed").innerHTML = "Pushed: " + "<em>" + push + "</em>" + "<br>" + "<br>" + array.toString() + "<hr>";
        menu();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Consider: `while (push != null)`. This will only enter the loop if the test is true. You don't change the value of *push* inside the loop, so its value will not change and so it will never exit the loop.

Comment: I don't understand if you want it to display array like in the first code why are you writing "Pushed: ....." in your code ?

Comment: @Burawi The "Pushed: ...." Just shows what item the user pushed, then I want it to add onto the array, and display as I showed above. Right now I just have it displaying in a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the above code would result in infinite loop as push is never reinitialized to null.

Here is what I come up with:

```
<script>
var array = ["cat", "dog"];
window.onload = function menu(){

var selection = prompt("Please use this menu, and type 1 to push an item on the array, 2 to pop an item off the array, and 3 to exit the menu.");
var push = null;
var index = 0;
  if (selection == '1'){
     push = prompt("What item would you like to push onto the array?");
      while (push != null) {    
        array.push(push);
       // document.getElementById("pushed").innerHTML = "Pushed: " + "<em>" + push + "</em>" + "<br>" + "<br>" + array.toString() + "<hr>";

       var html = "Pushed: <em>" + push + "</em><br>";
       var list = '';
       var len = array.length;
       for(var i = 0;i<len;i++){
       list = list +"["+i+"] "+array[i]+'<br/>';
       }
       document.getElementById("pushed").innerHTML = html+list;
         // make push null to avoid infinite loop.
       push= null;
        menu();
        }
    } 
} 

</script>
```

Here is a fiddle, which can help you.

https://jsfiddle.net/vozhuuq4/

Comment: Wow that is exactly how I wanted to do that! Thanks dude I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the:

```
while (push != null) {}
```

for an if, because that piece of code is never executing.

```
if (push != null) {}
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

You can store value in array as properties

```
var array = [];
window.onload = function menu(){

var selection = prompt("Please use this menu, and type 1 to push an item on the array, 2 to pop an item off the array, and 3 to exit the menu.");

if (selection == '1'){
var push = prompt("What item would you like to push onto the array?");
  while (push != null) {    
    array[array.length-1] = push;
    document.getElementById("pushed").innerHTML = "Pushed: " + "<em>" + push + "</em>" + "<br>" + "<br>" + array.toString() + "<hr>";
    menu();
    }
 } 
}
```

Comment: I have to start out my array with having the cat and dog in it. And I want it to show the index of the array in a list with the item it correlates too, but I appreciate your help.

Comment: for innitializing array try like this var array = {"0": "Dog", "1": "cat"};